# SSRS Page Breaks not working for PDF & Print View

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a SSRS report to put together letters parts of a letter to be sent to a contact(s) for an entity.

I have a Tablix of multiple rows to be made visible or hidden based on the data.

In each of those rows is a subreport.

I am trying to make each row start on a new page.

Setting Page Break to after (or before, or between) works on the screen, but not in Print Layout or a rendered PDF.

The Tablix has groups (entity_name, contact_id). This way it starts with company ABC, then builds a packet for Contac #1, Contact #2, Contact #3 ... then go to company DEF and their contacts ... and so on.

In the contact_id group I have multiple header rows.  Each row contains a rectangle and each rectangle contains a subreport.

The row is made visible/hidden based on the data.

I need each row/subreport to start on its own page.

I have set each subreport-holding rectangle to Page Break after in the Rectangles Properties.
I have set each Row PageBreak/BreakLocation to End in the Properties pane for the row.
I have set the PageBreak options to **Between each instance of a group** in the group propeerties (all of the groups)

*It breaks in the browser view of the report.
It does NOT break in Page Layout or when rendered to PDF.*

This report is to be printed and sent to our clients.

Does it have to be in the footer instead of the header?
Does it have to be in the details section?
Can only one section be fitted with Page Break, and if so which one?

Thank you for your help.